# TypeError of the metaclass in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote the follow program but it didn't work.What wrong with it?

```
def h(self):
    print "Hello World"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello = type('HelloThread', bases=(threading.Thread,object), dict=dict(hello=h))
```

The error when it run is that:

```
TypeError: type.__init__() takes no keyword arguments
```

My python version is the python2.7

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the expected output?

Answer (score 3):

The error specifically says `type.__init__() takes no keyword arguments` so don't use keyword arguments when initiating `type`:

```
hello = type('HelloThread', (threading.Thread, object), dict(hello=h))
```